# After a time playing, the cars lose the exterior of the chasis

Tags: mods, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

For some reason, after a few minutes of gameplay the vehicles that I have installed (mods) will loose part of the chassis:

[image: Whops]

Just in case, this is how the car should be:

[image: My sister says that this is kawaii]

I installed a few car mods, but the one on the picture if [this one](http://www.nfscars.net/need-for-speed-most-wanted/7/files/view/15222/).

What is the cause of this bug/glitch?

If more information is required, I have no problem on showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with High Polygon number models thanks to how memory management works in-game.

There's no solution to this problem other than reducing the Polygon count on the addon vehicle.

Source: [RRRRickk and ashthenyan on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/needforspeed/comments/484nuk/glitch_with_nfsmw_2005_car_body_disappears_in_the/)